# Apache Spark MLlib WSSSE Error

Tags: apache-spark

Can anybody please tell me what exactly is "Within Set Sum of Squared Error (**WSSSE**)" and computeCost method in **KMeansModel** in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard KMeans algorithm aims at minimizing the sum of squares of the distance between the points of each set: the squared Euclidean distance. This is the WCSS objective.
Once you have computed the `val result = KMeans.train(<trainData>, <clusterNumber>, <Iterations>)` you can evaluate the result by using Within Set Sum of Squared Errors (something like the sum of the distances of each observation in each K partition) :

```
val error = result.computeCost(<trainData>)
```

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with other responses on the explanation of WSSSE.  Just want to add that mean WSSSE is a better metric than WSSSE.  WSSSE is larger with size of dataset whereas mean WSSSE is better measure of cohesiveness of cluster.

WSSSE: 
The standard `KMeans` algorithm aims at minimizing the sum of squares of the distance between the points of each set: the squared Euclidean distance. This is the WCSS objective. Once you have computed the `val result = KMeans.train(<trainData>, <clusterNumber>, <Iterations>)` you can evaluate the result by using Within Set Sum of Squared Errors (something like the sum of the distances of each observation in each `K partition`) :

```
val error = result.computeCost(<trainData>)
```

Comment: Please don't refer to 'the next post down' as the answers get shuffled as they are added and edited. I replaced it with "another poster's", but recommend you edit it, and use the format @*user* to identify the member who wrote the post you're referring to or click the share link below the answer and paste a link to the actual answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think WSSSE or SSE (Sum of Squared Error) is not well explained from KMean's perspective here. This presentation describes it better http://www.cs.uky.edu/~jzhang/CS689/PPDM-Chapter3.pdf

Essentially SSE is, for each observed data point, we calculate the euclidian distance between that observed data point and cluster/centroid. We sum all the distances and that gives us SSE.

The intuition is that if the clusters/centroids are close to the data points they group then SSE will be low. But once can always increase K and get lower SSE but poor segments (anyway, that's a separate discussion).